# Detect substring in specific format

Tags: c, string, format, substring

What is the simplest way to detect a substring in a specific format?

For example, consider the string in C

```
"[random characters/symbols] a-b-c [random characters/symbols]"
```

Is there a function in C that allows me to detect the substring in the format "%s-%s-%s"?

Comment: You mean something like a regular expression?

Comment: `'-'` scans into `"%s"`.  Do you expect `"%s"` to not include `'-'`?  ``"%s"` includes everything that is not a white-space.

Comment: Do the random characters and symbols include spaces?  Are the characters in the `a-b-c` part separated from the random material by the spaces as shown?  Are you looking for three lower-case letters?  Three letters?  The alphanumerics? Do you need the values corresponding to `a`, `b` and `c` in the calling code?  You should probably be using `%c` or maybe `%1s` to avoid the first `%s` eating all the non-blanks, leaving the conversion failing on the `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting at various points within the string until success.

`"%*[^- ]` look for a sub-string that does not contain a `'-'` nor space.

`"%n` Record the offset in the scan.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s = "[random characters/symbols] a-b-c [random characters/symbols]";

  while (*s) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s, "%*[^- ]-%*[^- ]-%*[^- ]%n", &n);
    if (n) {
      printf("Success '%.*s'\n", n, s);
      break;
    }
    s++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Success 'a-b-c'
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I will have to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Use strchr() or strnchr() if you have it to detect a literal string (no pattern matching).  The function strnchr() is better because you can specify a max length to protect against a string with a missing null terminator; but, it is not ANSI so not all languages have it.  If you use strchr() make sure you protect against a missing null terminator.

You can use regcomp() to do a regular expressions search the string.
See [regex in C language using functions regcomp and regexec toggles between first and second match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377631/regex-in-c-language-using-functions-regcomp-and-regexec-toggles-between-first-an)

Comment: By definition, strings don't have missing null terminators; strings are terminated by the null byte.  Some byte sequences that should be strings are not because the null terminator is missing from the data in the array which holds the bytes, but such byte sequences are not strings.  The first sentence in the C standard, section 7.1.1 **Definition of terms** is: _A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character._  A string is null terminated — full stop.

Comment: Yep, that is the definition; but, there is nothing in the language that enforces it and it is painful to find when it happens.  You can claim all the semantics you; but, if you don't consider a missing null terminator in your code you risk instability.  As a SW developer we are responsible for functionality, stability, and maintainability not making sure my curly braces are in the right place.